# How to make manually-added Vue component show up in Vue dev tools?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-devtools

I'm mouting a component manually, just like docs say:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount

```js
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>Hello!</div>'
})

// or, render off-document and append afterwards:
var component = new MyComponent().$mount()
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(component.$el)
```

This works, but the component is not detected by Vue dev tools (by design: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/1425). Is there any other way to add ad hoc defined or imported components, so that it will show up inside Vue dev tools?

Purpose: I'm implementing dialog-like UI, where each dialog is a separate component that could be revealed at any time on any "page". The usage is restricted to Vue browser (no Single File Components).